# Cannot cast result of getSingleResult()

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm trying to get project by number,as below:

```
public Project getProjectByNum(String numProject) {
        Project project = new Project();

        try {

            Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM `project` WHERE `numProject` = '"+numProject+"';");
            project = (Project) q.getSingleResult();

        } catch (Exception exep) {
            exep.printStackTrace();
            tools.Tools.traiterException(tools.Tools.getStackTrace(exep));
        }
        return project;
     }
```

But , get always this error: **java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to entitiesMysql.Project**

How I can fix it?

Comment: Try casting it to `(Object[])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code,

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM project WHERE numProject = '"+numProject+"';", Project.class);
```